# Spark in Kubernetes container does not see local file

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit, nosuchfileexception

I have a trivially small Spark application written in Java that I am trying to run in a K8s cluster using `spark-submit`. I built an image with Spark binaries, my uber-JAR file with all necessary dependencies (in `/opt/spark/jars/my.jar`), and a config file (in `/opt/spark/conf/some.json`).

In my code, I start with

```java
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("myapp")
.config("spark.logConf", "true")
.getOrCreate();

Path someFilePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/opt/spark/conf/some.json");
String someString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(someFilePath));
```

and get this exception at `readAllBytes` from the Spark driver:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/spark/conf/some.json
```

If I run my Docker image manually I can definitely see the file `/opt/spark/conf/some.json` as I expect. My Spark job runs as root so file permissions should not be a problem.

I have been assuming that, since the same Docker image, with the file indeed present, will be used to start the driver (and executors, but I don't even get to that point), the file should be available to my application. Is that not so? Why wouldn't it see the file?

Comment: please share your image, share your kubernetes deployment/pod in YAML  format?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to get this exception from one of your worker nodes, not from the container.

Make sure that you've specified all files needed as `--files` option for `spark-submit`.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files <local files dependecies> ...
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "from one of your worker nodes, not from the container" -- the exception appears in the Spark driver log. And, given that the file in question is a part of the Docker image, I am under the impression that `--files` is unnecessary...

Comment: @mustaccio How is your application deployed? Driver is not necessarily run inside your docker container, it could be